# How to calculate average of arrays from array list?

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, average

I have an ArrayList in VB.NET.

For example ArrayList has two arrays: `AList(arr,arr)`:

```
Dim AList As ArrayList = New ArrayList((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
                                       (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11))
```

All I want is average of given arrays so:

So final Array will be `(1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5.........10.5)`

**Note:** Arraylist count and length of arrays will variable.

I tried the following code:

```
For k = 0 To 9 
    Dim sum As Short 
    Dim a As Array 

    For z = 0 To 1 
        sum = sum + AList.Item(a(k)) 
    Next 

    finalarr(k) = sum / 2 
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(finalarr(k)) 
Next
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am bit new to vb.net but have tried following code                                   
         For k = 0 To 9
            Dim sum As Short
            Dim a As Array
            For z = 0 To 1
                sum = sum + AList.Item(a(k))
            Next
            finalarr(k) = sum / 2
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(finalarr(k))
        Next

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you tried and use the formatting button to format it as code.  It'll be a *lot* easier to read that way

Comment: Will all the arrays inside the ArrayList be the same size?

Comment: yes all arrays will have same size

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim count As Inetger = 0
Dim avgList As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)()

For Each arr As Integer() In AList
    i = 0
    count += 1
    For Each thing as Integer In arr
        i += 1
        If avgList.Count >= i Then
            avgList.Item(i) = ((avgList.Item(i) + thing) / count)
        Else
            avgList.Add(i)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I wanted to get addition of all the arrays(for given indices) in arraylist. if you see result array above, it will help you to understand what i meant.

Comment: I modified your code to get the answer I wanted, Thanks.

Comment: Hi, The problem I am facing now is, When i loop through list and try to calculate it shows last item only, seems it overriding var each time for loop. can you help with that one?

Comment: Edit your current code into the question and we'll take a look.